# How does the Creep Releaser work?

Tags: awesomenauts

On the AI Station 404 map, there are buttons on the map called [Droid Releasers](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/AI_Station_404#Droid_Releaser) which create flying droids that help attack enemy turrets.

Is there a limit on the number of flying droids that can be released at a time? Is there a waiting period between when droids can be released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Patch 2.6 (released August 28th 2014), AI Station 404 has been replaced by [AI Station 205](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/AI_Station_205) in standard online matches. However, both maps are available in bot or custom matches, and both feature Droid Releasers, though the mechanics are slightly different between the two.

In both maps, **a maximum of 3 Humming Droids** can be spawned at a time from one team's Droid Releaser. Droids will be restocked one at a time after a certain interval, as long as the combined number of active and stored droids don't exceed 3. **On AI Station 404, it's 10 seconds** for each restock, while **on AI Station 205, it's 15 seconds**. The restocking timer doesn't start until there's a "slot" open, i.e. if you have 3 droids active, the timer doesn't start until at least one has been destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

Well, as I know, they are unlimited, but you just can release one group each, that means, that until the last "dragonfly" bot is destroyed, you can release one new group.